# CAML query to retrieve a list of users items with ids in a list

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010, caml

I am a beginner in SharePoint using CAML query to get a list of user items from a SharePoint list.

The data I have is a `userid` list like below:

1
2
3
4
5

Now I want to write a CAML query to retrieve the user items from a SharePoint list where the `userid` is in **(1,2,3,4,5)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to filter data by user ID you need to set LookupId="TRUE" for Author field:

```
<Eq>
  <FieldRef Name="Author" LookupId="TRUE" />
  <Value Type="Integer">1</Value>
</Eq>
```

If you want to use multiple values for this field you should check [IN Element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff625761.aspx). So your CAML should look like this:

```
 <In>
  <FieldRef Name="Author" LookupId="True" />
  <Values>
    <Value Type="Integer">1</Value>
    <Value Type="Integer">2</Value>
    <Value Type="Integer">3</Value>
  </Values>
</In>
```